# Union of multiple shapefiles (polygons) in ArcMap creates random vertical and horizontal lines (sections) in output

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, shapefile, union

I have made a union of 4 features (polygon shapefiles) in ArcMap. However in the final output it has made random completely vertical/horizontal lines/sections in the final union. So it should look like this:

[image]

But it actually turns out to look like this:

[image]

Not sure why this is happening, any ideas of how to solve this?

Comment: Try Dissolve tool

Comment: That doesn't work, it dissolves everything leaving only the outline

Comment: I think those lines are coming out of adaptive tile processing - see https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/supplement/tiled-processing-of-large-datasets.htm

Comment: Thank you, this does indeed seem to be what it is. Do you know if there is a way to recombine the subdivided tiles after processing?

Comment: You probably need to Repair Geometry on one or more of the source layers.

Comment: The only solution that works in this situation - convert to raster and back, unless you'd like to merge them in editing session.

Comment: Repairing geometries didn't seem to work, will try converting to raster and back. Thanks